# Testing Angular service depending on private functions

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I want to test an Angular service with Karma and Jasmine. Testing of the public function works as expected. But while testing not all lines of the service are covered because some lines within private functions are not reached. The reason is the private function depends on private states/variables.

Angular service:

```
// depends on something locally
var switch = false;

// private
function help() {
  if (switch) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

// public
this.func = function() {
  // ...
  help();
  // ...
}
```

With this sample only the false path of ther help function is covered.
Is there any way to test all paths of the service without making private functions public or to create setter?